# Call a php NuSoap webservice with Basic Authentication from a C# console app

Tags: c#, php, web-services, authorization, nusoap

The Issue is the credentials are not being passed, here's the code I have

```
caseTracking.wsCaseTracking  ct = new caseTracking.wsCaseTracking();
ct.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("test", "*********");
Uri uri = new Uri("http://exampleURL.com");
ICredentials credentials = netCredential.GetCredential(uri, "Basic");

ct.Credentials = credentials;
ct.PreAuthenticate = true;
string exists = ct.wsCaseExists("12345678", "12345");
```

Fiddler 2 Auth tab says

No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.

No Authorization Header is present.

This only works in SoapUI if 
Pre-emptive Auth: Authenticate pre-emptively is ticked

the php auth is:

```
function doAuthenticate(){
$authorized = false;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) && strlen($_SERVER
['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']) > 0 && !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && !isset
($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))  {
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' ,   
base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
if( strlen($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) == 0 || strlen($_SERVER
['PHP_AUTH_PW']) == 0 ) {
unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);
unset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
}
}

if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ) {
if($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == config_item('soap_username') && $_SERVER  
['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == config_item('soap_password') ) $authorized = true;
}
return $authorized;
}
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, thanks in advance